# jquery modal -- well that's ugly, what's wrong with my modal?

Tags: jquery, jquery-dialog

I created a quick modal dialog window and when I open it in FireFox, there's a non-faded band that goes right across the screen (see [image: here]). This doesn't happen in Chrome.

Any idea what's going on?

---

jquery:

```
  $("#add_route").click(function(){
    $("#create_route").dialog("open");
  });

  $("#create_route").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 200,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
```

html:

```
<div id="create_route" title="Create New Route">
  Please choose a lead for this new route:<br>
</div>
```

Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/RHkWh/1/)

---

Naturally, it works on jsfiddle, but not on my project....

Comment: Thats weird.. can u create a jsfiddle? Without access to your code, its very difficult to say whats going wrong.

Comment: chrome is sometimes more forgiving with improper html , could you post html and the jquery, or jsfiddle?

Comment: my code doesn't even work in jsFiddle, perhaps that's my problem?

Comment: updated your fiddle to include jquery UI and it works on IE,Chrome and Firefox

Comment: oops, forgot to click that (still newish to jsfiddle). See, I don't see how such a simple bit of code can make such a wierd render issue. Perhaps it's my computer? Maybe it will go away? In any event, it seems like it's localized to me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RHkWh/2/ I think you're trying too hard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using ASP.Net MVC generated project. But I'm experiencing the same issue when using it. And I find the background of that overlay is defined as this: background: #aaaaaa url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
That ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png is a 100-px high white image, which is exactly the white band comes from.
Hope this can help.